# Проблема "Не повторяйся" как связать код с тегами структур golang

Tags: golang

В Go теги структур часто используются для взаимодействия с базами данных. Например, в mongdodb такой тег `bson:"namekey"` соответствует документу у которого существует ключ с именем "namekey". Разумеется, к этому документу из когда может быть много обращений,а и так как получить доступ "просто так" нельзя приходиться дублировать код. Какой есть подход для решения задачи дублирования?

Пример:

```
type Category struct {
    Collection   *Collection
    DirPosters   string
    PrefixLength int
    Doc          CategoriesDoc
    Meta         *MetaInf
}

type CategoriesDoc struct {
    Name       string        `bson:"Name"`       
    URI        string        `bson:"URI"`       
    PosterName string        `bson:"PosterName"` 
    IDMetaInf  bson.ObjectId `bson:"_id_MetaInf"`
}

type MetaInf struct {
    Collection  *Collection
    ID          bson.ObjectId `bson:"_id"`
    Title       string        `bson:"Title"`
    Keywords    string        `bson:"Keywords"`
    Description string        `bson:"Description"`
}
func (v *Category) List() (js []byte, err error) {
            collection, session := v.Collection.get()
            defer session.Close()

            vidcat := []map[string]interface{}{}

            pipeline := []bson.M{
                bson.M{
                    "$lookup": bson.M{
                        "From":         v.Meta.Collection.Name,
                        "LocalField":   "_id_MetaInf", // ЗДЕСЬ НУЖЕН ТЕГ ИЗ СТРУКТРУРЫ CategoriesDoc
                        "ForeignField": "_id", // ЗДЕСЬ НУЖЕН ТЕГ ИЗ СТРУКТРУРЫ metainf
                        "As":           "MetaInf",
                    },
                },
            }

            err = collection.Pipe(pipeline).All(&vidcat)

            js, err = json.Marshal(&vidcat)
            if err != nil {
                return
            }
            return
        }
```

Comment: У вас пока слишком общее описание проблемы. Добавьте иллюстрирующий проблему код.

Comment: Добавил. Мне нужно объединить данные из двух коллекций mongodb. Для этого нужно использовать имена ключей нужных мне документов, а так как имена документов ассоциированы с тегами приходится теги дублировать.

Answer (score 0):

Перепробовал множество вариант. Сделал вывод, что самый простой - это хранить карту, в которой в качестве ключей выступают имена полей структуры, а в качестве значений значения тегов.

```
type kyes map[string]string

func (k *kyes) make(data interface{}, tagName string) {
    v := reflect.ValueOf(data)
    t := v.Type()

    m := *k

    for i := 0; i < t.NumField(); i++ {
        key := t.Field(i).Tag.Get(tagName)
        if key != "" {
            m[t.Field(i).Name] = key
        }
    }
}

type AnyDoc struct {
    ID       bson.ObjectId `bson:"_id"`
    Passwd   string        `bson:"passwd"`
    Username string        `bson:"username"`
    keys     kyes
}

func main() {
    a := AnyDoc{
        keys: make(kyes),
    }
    a.keys.make(a, "bson")
    fmt.Println(a.keys["Passwd"]) //  вывод passwd
}
```

Лучше этого варианта остаётся только кодогенерация, но это и так очевидно.